# Parent Div Selectors not Inheriting

Tags: html, css

I'm try to select the child selector of mouse-ico h5 yet it seems to be ignoring its' parents.  What am I misunderstanding about this?

```css
.mouse-ico>h5 {
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  color: #009587 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="mouse-scroll-cont">
  <div class="mouse-ico">
    <h5>Scroll for More Information</h5>
    <img src="sites/all/themes/ft_custom/assets/ico-mouse.png" alt="Scroll Icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. Not sure what should be inherited, though.

Comment: Just as a side note, if you don't need to use `!important`, it is best practice not to.

Comment: Seems like it works for me.

Comment: Ahh I was try to  select just the h5 for that specific div and change its' values -- it's completely ignoring the css.

Comment: @MasterSplinter "it's completely ignoring the css" In this example or in your actual page? This example seems to work the way you are stating you want.

Comment: In my page --  this was something I hard coded into a drupal tpl file.  It's so simple I don't see why it would not work.

Comment: You may need to be more specific to overwrite the current style. You could use your browser Dev Tools to see where the element's style is coming from and what selector you need to use to overwrite it.

Comment: I think the issue is that h5 is defined as a less variable and I was trying to override with css.

Comment: Hard to say, if you have not defined class `mouse-scroll-cont`. But else it seems like all is OK.

Comment: Got it to work I just had to be super exact with my selection.  You were right thanks!